# Unable to cast object of type Mediaplayer to type IMediaPlayerSource2

Tags: c#, uwp, playlist

I try to add a Playlist to the BackgroundMediaPlayer like this. So it looks like this:

```
try
{
    Progr.IsActive = true;
    ErrorMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    //This fills the ObservableCollection timeLine with Tracks
    await UserAuthed.PopulateTimelineTracksAsync(timeLine);

    //This should create the Playlist
    CreatePlaylist(timeLine);

    Progr.IsActive = false;
}

catch (Exception ex) 
{
    Progr.IsActive = false;
    ErrorMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}


private void CreatePlaylist(ObservableCollection<Collection> TrackCollection)
{
    foreach (var item in TrackCollection)
    {
        MediaSource ms = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(item.origin.uri));
        ms.CustomProperties.Add("Title", item.origin.title);
        ms.CustomProperties.Add("Artist", item.origin.user.username);
        MPL.Items.Add(new MediaPlaybackItem(ms));
    }

    BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Source = MPL;
}
```

But at `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Source = MPL;` he fails with `{"Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer' to type 'Windows.Media.Playback.IMediaPlayerSource2'."}`

What is this exception meaning? How can i fix it?

Edit: MPL is MediaPlaybackList.

Comment: Fails at compile-time, or execution time? What is the type of `MPL`?

Comment: `MPL` might be `MediaPlaybackList` type. Is it so?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, MPL is MediaPlaybackList

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code, with this:

```
private void CreatePlaylist(ObservableCollection<Collection> TrackCollection)
{
    // Make a new list
    MPL = new MediaPlaybackList();
    foreach (var item in TrackCollection)
    {
        MediaSource ms = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(item.origin.uri));
        ms.CustomProperties.Add("Title", item.origin.title);
        ms.CustomProperties.Add("Artist", item.origin.user.username);
        MPL.Items.Add(new MediaPlaybackItem(ms));
    }

    BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Source = MPL;
}
```

Here is complete GitHub [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BackgroundAudio/cs/BackgroundAudioTask/MyBackgroundAudioTask.cs) for your reference. At the end you can find the CreatePlaybackList function.

Thank You!

Comment: Might be issue in `item.origin.uri`.
Is you link fine?
Is uri accessible?
Do you add permission?

Comment: Now that you're saying it, this could be the problem. I'm working with the Soundcloud-API and the API doesn't give an http://xxxxxxxxx.mp3 Link as the Stream-Link. Maybe this is the problem.